# UnityでAndroidにビルドして実機で起動するとクラッシュする

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity2d

UnityでAppleStoreやGooglePlayにアプリをリリースしています。
突然Androidにビルドした後、実機で起動するとクラッシュしてすぐ落ちてしまいます。
以下はadb logcatでフィルタリングして表示したクラッシュ時のログです。

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
E/AudioPolicyManager(  447): getDeviceForStrategy() earpiece device not found
E/AudioPolicyManager(  447): getDeviceForStrategy() earpiece device not found
E/Vold    (  236): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.hoge.app/files/
E/SQLiteLog(18858): (283) recovered 22 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.hoge.app/databases/androidx.work.workdb-wal
E/WindowManager( 1012): Performed 6 layouts in a row. Skipping
E/Vold    (  236): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.hoge.app/files/
E/Vold    (  236): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/obb/com.hoge.app/
E/SQLiteLog( 5473): (2067) abort at 36 in [INSERT INTO pending_ops(service_kind,source,tag,requires_charging,target_package,source_version,required_network_type,flex_time,persistence_level,target_class,runtime,retry_strategy,preferred_n
E/CRASH   (18858): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
E/CRASH   (18858): Version '2020.3.32f1 (12f8b0834f07)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
E/CRASH   (18858): Build fingerprint: 'KDDI/KYV34_jp_kdi/KYV34:5.1/104.1.2940/104.1.2940:user/release-keys'
E/CRASH   (18858): Revision: '0'
E/CRASH   (18858): ABI: 'arm'
E/CRASH   (18858): Timestamp: 2022-06-01 00:00:53+0900
E/CRASH   (18858): pid: 18858, tid: 18915, name: UnityMain  >>> com.hoge.app >> com.hoge.app
```

クラッシュする原因や解決法のヒントになることを知っていれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。
ちなみに最近開発PCiMac2012からmacbookPro2015に変えています。それからクラッシュするようになったのでそれが関係していると自分では思っています。

### 実行環境

Unity 2020.3.32f1
macbook pro2015 Monterey
Android端末のバージョン 5.1

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクトを新規に作成し、そこにファイルを移してビルドしたら直りました。クラッシュの原因は分からないままですが解決したので良かったです。